# Menu doesn't update according navigationController

Tags: android, androidx, android-menu

Description:
Consider this flow: Fragment A -> Login -> Fragment B. You can navigate from A to Login through **top-right menu** (more actions icon).
I would like that after the uses reach Login, there is no way back. I mean

**Expected behavior:**

- User opens the app (fragment A)
- The user navigates to Login (no back button shown on the toolbar)
- User clicks back (native back (ONLY OPTION))
- App closes

I manage that with

```
 navigationController.navigate(
                        R.id.fragment_login, null, NavOptions.Builder()
                        .setPopUpTo(R.id.fragment_a, true)
                        .build()
)
```

**Actual behavior:**

- User opens app (fragment A)
- User navigates to Login -> back button keep being shown
- User clicks back

  - User clicks native back -> app closes as expected
  - User clicks toolbar back button -> it goes to fragment A

I have an example in https://github.com/rafaelaguerra/navigation_components_example/tree/menu_issue

Answer (score 0):

I managed it combining two `topLevelDestinationIds`

```
activity_base_toolbar_main.setupWithNavController(
        navController = navigationController,
        configuration =
        AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.fragment_login,
            R.id.fragment_a
        ).build()
    )
```

with

```
 override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.fragment_login -> {
                navigationController.navigate(
                        R.id.fragment_login, null, NavOptions.Builder()
                        .setPopUpTo(R.id.fragment_a, true)
                        .build()
                )
    ...
}
```

But for me it's still not a clean solution